# IDE tags are commonly misused

Tags: feature-request, tags

When reviewing, I often find that users have tagged their IDE in the question, even though the question is to do purely with code.

[bluej](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluej) seems to be particularly affected by this.

I assume this is often caused by users tagging in their IDE even if it's unlikely to be relevant to the problem.

I wonder if it's worth popping up a warning (maybe only for low rep users) if they use an IDE tag, saying something along the lines of, "This tag is for questions specific to Eclipse IDE; please only use the tag if the IDE is relevant to the question."

Comment: If they don't read the tag description, they're unlikely to read any sort of other message, sadly.

Comment: All client/IDE tags are regularly misused, "I'm accessing this through <blah> so the language I'm using is <blah>" is ridiculously common. If someone doesn't know what language they're using then I can't imagine a system message making much of a difference...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BlueJ isn't java. It's a tutorial language that is has extra stuff. So, when bluej questions are merely tagged java, java people reasonably shoot at them with 'that's not in Java, how does it even compile.' So, in my view, bluej as a tag is essential.

Comment: So, the wiki and excerpt are wrong? Care to correct them?