# How to stop people from misusing [brew]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

Questions related to the [homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homebrew) macOS package manager are often tagged with [brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew), because that’s the command it uses:

```
$ brew install ...
```

However, BREW ([brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew)) is already an application framework for mobile phones.

I started cleaning up the [brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew)-tagged questions [back in 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309705/735926) but they keep coming back. I’d say 80% of all questions tagged [brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew) at some point are related to Homebrew, not the BREW framework.

We could maybe rename [brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew) and/or merge it into [brewmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brewmp), then make [brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew) an alias for [homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homebrew).

Thoughts?

Comment: How to also stop people misusing [tag:flex] instead of using [tag:flexbox] ... even if the description is quite clear people don't read it

Comment: As in the [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) example that Temani brings up, I think that the problem with this tags is that the name is too generic. While ultimately the reponsability lies at the feet of whoever choses the wrong tag without reading the description, having a more descriptive name (like for example `flex-framework` or `brew-framework` would hopefully help more users to determine quickly that's not the tag they are looking for.

Comment: TL;dr of @yivi comment: you shouldn't need to read tag excerpt to use the tag.

Comment: @TemaniAfif For the `flex` one, it's quite understandable that people tag it for CSS flex. CSS flex is just too well-known, I'm actually surprised that this tag could mean something else here.

Comment: @liliscent It's not that strange really, Adobe Flex was pretty hyped for a (short) while before it was handed over to Apache. I'm more surprised it's still being used to be honest, it's the first time in 7 years I've even seen it mentioned.

Comment: @yivi - In theory, sure. In reality, if users can still get the [batch-file] and [batch-processing] tags mixed up on a daily basis, I'm not too optimistic.

Comment: Actually, the first association I have with `flex` is the tool for building lexical analysers.

Comment: @Giorgio: I am okay with just [tag:lex], as the difference between them (except for speed and licencing) is not that great. However, the asymmetry between [tag:lex] vs [tag:flex-lexer] bugs me a bit. :)

Comment: Lets keep in mind that this question is not about the flex tag though ;)

Comment: @Amadan: IMHO if a term is ambiguous, it should always be qualified. Therefore: `flex-framework`, `flex-css`, `flex-lexer`. Similarly `homebrew` and `brew-framework`. Since the tag `brew` is ambiguous I would remove it altogether.

Comment: TL;dr this entire conversation: don't sacrifice clarity for brevity.

Comment: `brew` isn't the only to see this unfortunately. Related questions on IDE's: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288993/ide-tags-are-commonly-misused https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315195/6296561 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326237/6296561 - the only current ways to deal with this is removing it. I'd definitively vote for anything that helps fight tag abuse, specifically for common misuses (such as this one, or IDE tags). Some of these even have explicit warnings, but no one seems to read them. Also applies to the burnination of the design tag. Few read the "do not use" warning.

Comment: @TemaniAfif same with [tag:edge] vs [tag:microsoft-edge] and countless other tags, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Giorgio we do have a naming scheme for most thing with CSS: `[css-*]` so in this case it would be [tag:css-flexbox]. Perhaps a tag renaming and synonym association by a CM would solve that problem

Comment: How can I get a moderator to rename `brew` into `brew-framework`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now completed. I retagged all the new questions from the past 2 days (all were related to Homebrew) and renamed the tag from [brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew) to [brew-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew-framework)

I also added [brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew) as a synonym to [homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homebrew), so that users don't recreate the tag, for either of its meanings.

---

<sub>I had ignored this post a few days back, thinking that most of the questions were related to brew and not Homebrew, but turns out that the [OP was editing the tag out every time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/735926/bfontaine?tab=activity&sort=revisions). That is some commendable effort by the OP</sub>